# Improve performance of List<T>

Tags: c#

I have a class called Product that contains some properties like Id (as Guid) and Messages (as List), and a Message class that also contains Id and other properties. I have all messages in Message table and all products in product table. After getting data of both tables, I want to join them regarding on Id property. If I use the below code as it is linear search the performance is terrible.

```
foreach (Product product in products)
    product.Messages = messages.Where(n => n.Id == product.Id).ToList();
```

Are there any other ways to do it faster?

Thanks

Comment: Join on database side ? If you absolutely need it to work on the client side, I would use a dictionary.

Comment: Why aren't you performing the join on the database side? That's going to be an order of magnitude faster than pulling all the data in, and the performing it in C#.

Comment: If you're using entityframework then you shouldn't have to do any of this

Comment: Good question by the way, generated a lot of interesting discussion.

Comment: I need to have all records in client side. So, prefer to join them in C#. Anyway, ToLookup solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to speed it up by groupding your messages into a lookup table.

```
messagesDict = messages
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x.ToList());
```

or, as John Bustos suggested, you can use ToLookup();

```
messagesDict = messages
    .ToLookup(x => x.Id);
```

you use it like this

```
//you might have to first check if messagesDict 
//actually has any messages for your project.
product.Messages = messagesDict[product.Id];
```

Your original attempt is **O(nm)** where **n** is the number of projects and **m** is the number of messages.

A `Dictionary` uses hashing, so from a *practical* standpoint, you can usually assume that it has close to **O(1)** inserts, and **O(1)** searches.  [Under ideal circumstances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx), `List<T>.Add` is also **O(1)**. This means that if you were to manually create your lookup dictionary, then, you could do it in **O(m)**.  I would hope that a built-in function like `ToLookup`, achieves the same efficiency.

Once you do that, your algorthim becomes **O(n + m)**

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to the punch :(

Comment: @Sam I made a mistake. Id is not int. it is Guid. So, Does your solution still work?

Comment: Grouping is not sorting, is it? Do we know if the Group() method internally uses a sorting algorithm?

Comment: @Babi which `Id` is not an int?  so long as they're both the same type, it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @Sam Yes, they are the same. I am going to try it :)

Comment: So your basic idea refers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: I was actually about to ask the same thing @ThomasWeller - if it uses sorting that would make it either O(n log n) or O(n^2) depending on the sorting algorithm. The other question is the computational complexity of ToDictionary - if that's O(n) too obviously doing this operation wouldn't improve the computational complexity.

Comment: @ThomasWeller no, this answer does not rely on branch prediction.

Comment: @EJoshuaS This is a practical answer.  It works for scenarios where you have a realistic number of projects and a realistic number of messages.  For realistic data sets, Dictionary reads have **O(1)** runtime complexity.  If you wanted to optimize this algorithm for your theory of CS homework, then you would do it differently.

Comment: @SamIam my question was about the effects of GroupBy and ToDictionary, I think that the analysis you added answers that well though.

Comment: @Sam your solution worked for me with a huge performance improvement. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing the join in the database. That'll yield the best performance. If you insist on doing this in C# sort product by Id and sort messages by ID first.

Comment: I agree with doing it in the database since you can search a B-Tree in O(log n) time. However, sorting by ID first in C# would actually be worse in my opinion; linear search is O(n) but most sorting algorithms are either O(n log n) or O(n^2), see http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @EJoshuaS Unless you have a much larger benefit after sorting by branch prediction. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: @EJoshuaS, that's assuming that products are 1 to many with messages, which while likely, isn't at all indicated in the question. And as Thomas mentioned, branch prediction.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That's a fair point; that post you linked to explains the issue well. On the one hand, if you're doing an O(n^2) operation, for example, the algorithm as a whole couldn't possibly be any better than O(n^2), but looking at that post I can see how you could actually save time overall (even if you can't do better than the sorting algorithm in terms of computational complexity).

Comment: I suppose that, depending on the characteristics of the sorted list, you might be able to do a de facto binary search. Kind of reminds me of a problem I was given in an interview: suppose you have a sorted array with the ages of every individual in the world (so, for example, if you had 1,000,000 people of age 1 you'd have 1,000,000 consecutive 1's in the array). How do you count the number of people in an age group? To simplify, my answer was that the sorting lets you do a binary search variant to find the index of the first and last instance of that number and then subtract them to count.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, exactly why the O(n log n) sorting might be worthwhile.

Comment: @EJoshuaS  you don't even have to do a binary search in this case.  If you sort both projects and messages, then you can effectively iterate over both at the same time, resulting in __O(n lg(n) + m lg(m))__ runtime.

Comment: @SamIam fair point, that would be a pretty effective algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, do the join in the database. As you indicated, a linear search is O(n) (and you're actually doing quite a few linear searches in this case); however, most databases use a B-Tree data structure (or something similar) to sort rows by primary key. This means that a database search on a primary key is O(log n), which is obviously *dramatically* faster. (Assuming, of course, that the Id is the primary key).

Comment: I need to have all records in client side. So, prefer to join them in C#. Anyway, ToLookup solved my issue. Thanks :)